# how to implement VPN Kill Switch programatically in macOS

Tags: swift, macos

I want to implement VPN kill switch programatically. I could enable and disable `pf` manually from terminal.But I cant do it from my App.
 For this I loaded `pf.conf` file with rules:

```
"block drop all\n"
"pass inet proto udp from any to 224.0.0.0/4 keep state\n"
"pass inet proto udp from 224.0.0.0/4 to any keep state\n"
"pass inet from any to 255.255.255.255 flags S/SA keep state\n"
"pass inet from 255.255.255.255 to any flags S/SA keep state\n"
"pass on $active_interface proto tcp from any port 67:68 to any port 67:68 flags S/SA keep state\n"
"pass on $active_interface proto udp from any port 67:68 to any port 67:68 keep state\n"
"pass on $active_interface inet proto tcp from any to 109.201.137.13 flags S/SA keep state\n"
"pass on $active_interface inet proto udp from any to 109.201.137.13 keep state\n"
"pass on $VPN_interface all flags S/SA keep state\n"
```

It works fine with `sudo pfctl -e` and `sudo pfctl -d` when VPN is connected.If VPN is disconnected traffic will be blocked and user have to either connect to the von or disable the kill switch to avail the traffic.

For executing command from mac app I used privilege helper tool and I am getting `PF enabled` and 'PF disabled' as per the `pf` commands in the console, but the traffic is blocked all the time. I am using Swift for development

I was struggling with this for a week. Please help.
 Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.